# How to treat "unbalanced" predictor variables in partial least squares (PLS)?

Tags: r, caret, partial-least-squares

I am using partial least squares regression (PLS) to model the relative effects of soil and weather variables on the magnitude of an annual phenomenon, nitrous oxide emissions. I am doing this on an annual basis across many sites.

Soils at each site are different, but soils within each site stay the same every year.

Weather is different at every site and different from year to year.

I am using  the `pls` package in R. I think I did an okay job pre-processing my data (BoxCox, center, scale). I end up with 17 columns of soil properties (the properties repeated for each year, not unique rows), 5 columns of weather variables (each row unique) and my dependent variable nitrous oxide (each row unique).

I just need one line of code:

```
plsFit<-plsr(nitrous_oxide ~ ., validation = "LOO", data=all_data)
```

Everything runs great, but I can't help but feel the lack of balance.

**Should I really be treating soil and weather variables in the same way?**

Comment: I don't think the unbalance in the number of 'predictor variables' can cause a problem. Why do you think it can be?

Comment: My results show that soil characteristics have varying degrees of importance to nitrous oxide, but all weather variables have the same importance - none. I want to make sure this is not an artifact of how I run the model.